# Get multiple maximum values from an array of values

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

For example in `underscore/lowdash` you can use `_.max(list, [iterator], [context])` function to receive one maximum value. But I want to have it returned multiple maximum values if they are all equal.

```
var stooges = [{name: 'moe', age: 40}, {name: 'larry', age: 50}, {name: 'curly', age: 50}];

_.max(stooges, function(stooge){ return stooge.age; });

=> {name: 'curly', age: 50};
```

I want to have somthing like this:

```
var stooges = [{name: 'moe', age: 40}, {name: 'larry', age: 50}, {name: 'curly', age: 50}];

_.multiplemax(stooges, function(stooge){ return stooge.age; });

=> [{name: 'curly', age: 50},  {name: 'larry', age: 50 ];
```

Using underscore is ok.

Comment: Can it always return an array?

Comment: Obviously... result should be an array as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is there any special requirements like you cant not combine multiple functions to do multiplemax. If no, I have 2 solutions in my mind

The simplest solution would be to use _.max to find the max `age` of the array, then use _.filter to filter all values that are equal to max `age`

Another solution is to use _.groupBy to group the array by `age` and then get the group with max `age`

Something like this

```
function multiplemax(arr, compare) {
  var groups = _.groupBy(arr, compare);
  var keys = _.keys(groups);
  var max = _.max(keys);
  return groups[max];
}
```

more "underscore"

```
_.mixin({
  multiplemax: function(arr, fn) {
    var groups = _.groupBy(arr, fn);
    var keys = _.keys(groups);
    var max = _.max(keys);
    return groups[max];
  }
})
```

Or using `max` + `filter`

```
function multiplemax(arr, compare) {
  var max = _.max(arr, function(v){return v[compare]});
  return _.filter(arr, function(v){return v[compare]==max[compare]});
}
```

Comment: Note that the keys will be strings - so if you take the `more "underscore"` approach you may want to go for `var max = _.max(keys, function (d) { return parseInt(d, 10); });`

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick.

```
_.mixin({
    multiplymax: function(items, comparitor) {
        comparitor = comparitor || _.identity;
        var max = comparitor(items.pop());
        var found = [max];
        _.each(items, function(item) {
            var val = comparitor(item);
            if(val > max) {
                found = [item];//empty
                max = val;
            } else if (val === max) {
                found.push(item);
            }
        });

        return found;
    }
})
```

Update fixed the broken code ;)

```
_.multiplymax([{age: 1}, {age:5}, {age:7}, {age:7}, {age:3}], _.property("age")); // [{age:7}, {age:7}]
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
var stooges = [{name: 'moe', age: 40}, {name: 'larry', age: 50}, {name: 'curly', age: 50}];

_.mixin( { multiplemax: function(list, field){

    var max = _.max(list, function(item){
        return item[field];
    });

    return _.filter(list, function(item){
        return item[field] === max[field];
    });
}});    

var oldStooges = _.multiplemax(stooges, 'age');
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a modern version using TypeScript & ES6:

```
const multipleMaxBy = <T>(list: T[], iteratee: (element: T) => number) => {
  const maxScore = Math.max(...list.map(iteratee));
  return list.filter((element) => iteratee(element) === maxScore);
};
```